# api на одном компьютере возвращает статус 200, на другом 401,хотя код один и тот же

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

я авторизовался на сервере с api, делаю axios запрос с параметром wtihCredentials" true и на одном нотбуке мне приходит ответ, что я авторизован, а если делаю этот же запрос на макбуке возвращает статус 401, хотя я авторизован на сервере

Comment: Если в авторизации участвуют сертификаты, то м.б. на Маке он стал недействительным?

Comment: как именно авторизуешься? На какой сервер делаешь запрос? В приватном режиме или нет?

Comment: в респонсе приходит вот такая ошибка: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers и не могу понять, почему на одном компе работает нормально, а на другом выдаёт эту ошибку